# MongoDB - Get latest non-null field value from documents with timestamp

Tags: mongodb

In the MongoDB collection I'm querying, each document represents some data for a parcel at a specific time. Every time I receive an update for a parcel, some fields may be updated (non-null value) and some others are not (null values).

To illustrate, consider this example. We received 3 data sets for a parcel:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "parcelNum" : "CC123456789FR",
    "datetime" : ISODate("2018-09-05T10:48:38.584Z"),
    "field1" : "value1_1",
    "field2" : "value2_1"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "parcelNum" : "CC123456789FR",
    "datetime" : ISODate("2018-09-05T10:48:40.566Z"),
    "field1" : "value1_2",
    "field2" : null
}

/* 3 */
{
    "parcelNum" : "CC123456789FR",
    "datetime" : ISODate("2018-09-05T10:48:42.777Z"),
    "field1" : null,
    "field2" : "value2_2"
}
```

**How can I extract the latest non-null value, for all fields, considering the timestamp of the document they belong to?**

Using the previous example, this is what I try to get:

```
{
    "parcelNum" : "CC123456789FR",
    "field1" : "value1_2",
    "field2" : "value2_2"
}
```

I tried that kind of query but I can't find how to mix field values from multiple documents:

```
db.testDB.aggregate([
    {$sort: { datetime: -1 }},
    {$group: { _id: "$parcelNum", 
        field1: {$first: "$field1" },
        field2: {$first: "$field2" }
    }}
])
```

gives me:

```
{
    "_id" : "CC123456789FR",
    "field1" : null,
    "field2" : "value2_2"
}
```

which is wrong because it only uses values from the most recent document and doesn't mix all the documents.

I tried another approach suggested by Rishi in another topic. Instead of creating a new document for each revision, he suggested pushing revision sub-documents onto an array and maintaining the latest revision at the parent document.

Something like this:

```
{
    parcelNum: CC123456789FR,
    lastUpdated: ISODate("2018-09-05T10:48:42.777Z")
    field1: "value1_2",
    field2: "value2_2",
    revisions: [
        {
            datetime: ISODate("2018-09-05T10:48:38.584Z"),
            field1: "value1_1",
            field2: "value2_1"
        },
        {
            datetime: ISODate("2018-09-05T10:48:40.566Z"),
            field1: "value1_2",
            field2: null
        },
        {
            datetime: ISODate("2018-09-05T10:48:42.777Z"),
            field1: null,
            field2: "value2_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, maintaining the latest revision is not that easy because updates are not received in a chronological order then I can receive a "new" document which has an older "datetime" field value and then I must not update the fields except if they are null. Therefore, I would have to record the last update timestamp for all fields if I want to do so!

Comment: "would have to record the last update timestamp for all fields if I want to do so!" - so? it's 32/64 bits per timestamp. I'd also add that instead of one document, you could probably better make mix -- one collection for the merged documents and another for all of them.

Comment: @AgostonHorvath: It was just for a matter of collection readability, not for a a matter of disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    //Sort
    {$sort: { datetime: -1 }},
    //Add fields to an array
    {$group: {
        "_id": null,
        "field1": { $push: "$field1" },
        "field2": { $push: "$field2" },
    }},

    //Filter and do not include null values
    {$project: {
        "field1notNull" : {
              $filter: {
               input: "$field1",
               as: "f",
               cond: { $ne: [ "$$f", null ] }
            }
          },
        "field2notNull" : {
              $filter: {
               input: "$field2",
               as: "f",
               cond: { $ne: [ "$$f", null ] }
            }
          }
        }
    },
    //Get the first values of each
    {$project: {
        "_id": null,
        "field1": {$arrayElemAt: ["$field1notNull", 0]},
        "field2": {$arrayElemAt: ["$field2notNull", 0]} 
    }}
])
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the not-null filtering?

We tweaked our collection to avoid inserting null fields then I try to simplify the query. I tried to remove the filtering and replace {$arrayElemAt: ["$field1notNull", 0]} by {$arrayElemAt: ["$field1", 0]} but it doesn't work... (return NULL value for the field).

Comment: Sorry, this comment was for @Juan I forgot to specify it.

Comment: Got it! I just needed to completely remove the first projection and not only some fields...

Comment: Alright, the first projection is only used to remove the null fields so it should be fine.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#pipe._S_facet) stage, to threat field1 and field2 separatly :

```
db['01'].aggregate(
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $sort: {
            "datetime":-1
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $facet: {parcelNum:[{$group:{_id:"$parcelNum"}}],
                field1: [ {
                        $match: {
                        field1:{$ne:null}
                        }
                    },      
                    {
                        $limit: 1
                    },
                    {
                        $project: {
                         _id:0,
                         field1:1
                         }
                    }, ],
                    
                field2: [ {
                        $match: {
                        field2:{$ne:null}
                        }
                    },      
                    {
                        $limit: 1
                    },
                    {
                        $project: {
                         _id:0,
                         field2:1
                         }
                    }, ],
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                parcelNum:"$parcelNum._id"  ,
                field1:"$field1.field1",
                field2:"$field2.field2",
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                parcelNum:{$arrayElemAt:["$parcelNum"  ,0]},
                field1:{$arrayElemAt:["$field1"  ,0]},
                field2:{$arrayElemAt:["$field2"  ,0]},
            }
        },
    ],
);
```

Note that stages 3 and 4 are only 'decorative', needed result is present at end of stage 2.
Hope it helps